# What is the proper way to setup MFP v7.1 App Center SSL with a self-signed CA certificate

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I need to know the proper way to setup the MobileFirst Application Center to use SSL (due to the requirement for supporting iOS v9 devices).
MobileFirst is v7.1 running on WebSphere Application Server ND v8.5.5.0.

I have reviewed the instructions from here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/c_ac_ssl_config.html

I was then navigated to here:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/admin/c_ssl_config.html%23c_ssl_config?lang=en

As advised, I created a self-signed certificate, like so:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout privateKey.key -out certificate.crt -reqexts v3_req -extensions v3_ca
```

The above two pages imply that all I need to do is to create a self-signed CA certificate and upload it to the AppCenter console.
Whilst this will allow the App Center Client to distribute the certificate for installation on the devices, I do not see how the "server-side" should be setup?

On the first link above, there is a sub-link to 'setting up SSL for WAS Full Profile', but, those instructions are for using a "proper" certificate and not a self-signed CA certificate.

Am I missing something obvious here? Creating the self-signed CA certificate and distributing it to the client device seems like only 1/2 a job.  I don't understand how, when using the Application Center Client, I enter the [user/pwd hostname/9443/applicationcenter] details and it will connect and authenticate using SSL to the Application Center.

Are there any straight forward instructions (or advice) that explain what the proper process is to setup Application Center for SSL to allow for iOS v9 devices to securely connect to the Application Center?

Answer (score 2):

WAS does not care if the certificate you are using is self-signed or not.  So the instructions in the first link you referenced are still applicable (except that, if you already have this certificate, you don't need to create a certificate signing request, so step #1 in the doc isn't necessary).

There is a blog post [here](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2015/09/07/preparing-ibm-mobilefirst-platform-server-app-transport-security-ios-9/) that discusses how to configure your server to work with iOS 9 App Transport Security.  This is not specific to Application Center.

Comment: Just to followup on this.  It turns out that adding the SSL cert to WAS in the normal way was standard.  The "bit" that was missing/needed was from the blog post, specifically the "add all of the ciphers" and change the "protocol".  After making those changes, it works perfect now.